# Intellisense for JavaScript and CSS files in separate solution

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, resharper

I have a Visual Studio 2013 solution that contains a project that has all my JavaScript files and Style Sheets.

My question is when I am developing in another solution (using Visual Studio 2013 with Asp.net MVC with Style and Scripts bundled and referenced on my `Layout` page) is there a way that I can get intellisense for my CSS or JavaScript files in my separate solution in my views?

P.S. I also have ReSharper 8.2 installed if anyone has any idea how I can make ReSharper work with it. I'm open to any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I use Web Essentials extension it works pretty good.

http://vswebessentials.com/